# Code based on Selenium not behaving after Chrome update

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I updated my browser from Chrome 75 to 77, along with the Selenium driver.  The code I wrote can no longer navigate through the website and always fails at the same stage when it shouldn't.

Has anything changed between these two versions that I need to edit within my code?

I wrote a program to take a vehicle reg checker, enter it into the government reg checker and return three bits of data to do with the car linked to that reg.

This is the line of code that is no longer working

```
python_button = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//input[@data-val='true'][@type='radio']")[0]
python_button.click()
```

Can't seem to get passed this stage - even though html linking the button seems to be correct. No matter whether the reg is a correct one or not my script returns  return([vehicleReg, "vehicle not found"])

I get the error message

python_button = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//input[@data-val='true'][@type='radio']")[0]

IndexError: list index out of range

My code is:

def vehicleRegTest('LK02USP'):

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://vehicleenquiry.service.gov.uk")

driver.find_element_by_name("Vrm").send_keys(vehicleReg)

python_button = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[@name='Continue'][@type='submit']")[0]
python_button.click()

python_button = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//input[@data-val='true'][@type='radio']")[0]
python_button.click()

python_button = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[@name='Continue'][@type='submit']")[0]
python_button.click()
```

Comment: It worked for me, try maximizing the browser `driver.maximize_window()`. You should also add some wait.

Comment: I've changed the code to this now... and still always get vehicle not found error back - it cant execute the code after the wait function

Comment: can you try `catch Exception as e` and `print(e)` and add it to the question?

Comment: All i get with that is "Message: "

The web page that gets opened can never execute this:

        python_button = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//input[@data-val='true'][@type='radio']")[0]
        python_button.click()

Comment: I am getting this now: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[name="Vrm"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=77.0.3865.90)